# Swift UITextView LayoutManager subclass

Tags: swift, uitextview, subclass, nslayoutmanager

I am trying to subclass a `UITextView`'s `layoutManager`

But keep getting crashes. The examples I have been looking at are in Objective C, so I'm getting a bit confused to how I am supposed to change the layoutManager

Here is my code...

```
class TextWrapLayoutManager: NSLayoutManager {

override func drawBackground(forGlyphRange glyphsToShow: NSRange, at origin: CGPoint) {
    self.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfGlyphs)) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, Bool) in
        let lineBoundingRect = self.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer)
        let adjustedLineRect = lineBoundingRect.offsetBy(dx: origin.x + 5, dy: origin.y + 2)
        let fillColorPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: adjustedLineRect, cornerRadius: 10)
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        fillColorPath.fill()
    }
}
```

}

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: canvasView.center.y - 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 130))

    textView.textContainer.layoutManager = TextWrapLayoutManager()

    textView.keyboardAppearance = .dark
    textView.textAlignment = .center
    textView.font = UIFont.attrctFont(ofSize: 32, weight: .bold)
    textView.textColor = textColor
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    textView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 5, bottom: 2, right: 5)
    textView.tintColor = .white
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.delegate = self
    self.canvasView.addSubview(textView)

    addGestures(view: textView)
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Using...

```
textView.textContainer.layoutManager = TextWrapLayoutManager()
```

Compliles but crashes on the next line.

What is the correct way to Subclass UITextView's LayoutManager?

Thanks

Comment: It crashes because the textContainer is unowned. So basically your instance dies right after setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `var textContainer` is `nil`.

Use this init

`init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?)`

passing a *non nil* textContainer.

After that you will be able to set your custom `layoutManager`